# Which way return HHOOK message to system is better?

Tags: c++, winapi, return, hook, message

I use a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook and *always return message to system*.
I wonder 2 ways bellow, which is better? I **think** way `//1` better performance because it send back message to system immediately, while `//2` must complete its stuff then send back, but I see almost people use `//2`. Help me to understand, thank!

```
HHOOK _l_hook

// 1
LRESULT __stdcall l_Callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CallNextHookEx(_l_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    //Do stuff
    return 0;
}

// 2
LRESULT __stdcall l_Callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //Do stuff
    CallNextHookEx(_l_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to return the result of calling `CallNextHookEx`, as per the documentation. Anyway, it shouldn't matter too much because, IIRC, there's a specific timeout for hook procedures.

Comment: Since you are worried about performance: There is no measurable difference. Regardless, both versions do not adhere to the rules spelled out in the documentation.

Comment: Docs say: _A hook procedure can call this function either before or after processing the hook information._ I'd say just stick to the standard `return CallNextHookEx(...)` at the end because if your callback is so expensive that calling next hook first or last would make any real difference then you are probably doing too much work there in the first place (and you might want offload that to another thread via queue or something, to keep the callback fast and simple).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of them are correct.  Boilerplate implementation should look like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DebugProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    if (nCode >= 0) {
       // do your stuff
       //...
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_l_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

You didn't specify the type of hook you implemented so it is unguessable if you'd have any reason at all to alter the pattern.  Always aim for "no".  Use the code samples in the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if in doubt.

Comment: I updated my question, that is WH_KEYBOARD_LL, I only need info about keystroke, and never handle it from system.

Comment: You can filter keys with that hook by returning -1 and not call CallNextHookEx().  It is optional.  My answer is still good, it handles both ways.